# how do I use the "in" operator? Flex/AS3

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript, flex3

So the documentation has this nifty "in" operator which I like the idea of more that using a multiple step or statement (||). The documentation gives me this example.

```
trace("PI" in Math);         // true
trace("myProperty" in Math); // false
```

and

```
public var myArray:Array = ["zero", "one", "two"];
trace(0 in myArray); // true
trace(1 in myArray); // true
trace("two" in myArray); // true
trace(3 in myArray); // false
```

So I try to use it like this:

```
var quickArray:Array = ["@icd9_color","@icd9_icd9","@templateIcd9_name","@templateIcd9_name","@templateIcd9_templateIcd9ID"];
return (element.dataField in quickArray);
```

Now I can trace or Alert.show() the element.datafield and it will match exactly with an array item, but it never returns true. Can anyone help me figure out why?

The only thing I can get to work this ugly thing:

```
return (
  element.dataField == "@icd9_color" ||
  element.dataField == "@icd9_icd9"
  etc..
)
```

Comment: `trace("two" in myArray);` actually returns false

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `in` operator checks whether an object has a specified property - *not* what the value of that property is.

You want to use `Array.indexOf` and check for a non-negative value.

Comment: Thanks I was getting quite aggravated by that.

Comment: So shouldn't trace("two" in myArray); output false instead of true in invertedSpear's test?